# Shopify + og:image resulting in "was not a valid URL."

Tags: facebook, shopify

This is the code:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="{{ 'logo.png' | asset_url }}" />
```

As you can see, I do have the file:

[image]

But if you check in the [Facebook Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fsunfoxcases.com%2F), you'll see this:

> Provided og:image URL,
>   //cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1318/9093/t/10/assets/logo.png?15320454113946669981
>   was not a valid URL.

Why is this problem and how to solve it?

Direct URL of the logo: https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1318/9093/t/10/assets/logo.png?15320454113946669981

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this `<meta property="og:image" content="https://{{ 'logo.png' | asset_url }}" />`

Facebook **scraper** requires the transfer protocol to be specified.